# Language defaulting to English instead of French for French French

Tags: ios, xcode, localization

My app is currently localized in English (en), French (fr), Danish (da), and base localization.

The problem is that on my French iPhone (fr_FR), the app is in English, while on my danish iPad, it is correctly localized.

In the iOS 13 language preferences of my app, I can see 4 languages: English, French, French (France) and Danish.

When I change to French, it is in French, while on French (France), the app is in English.

Why is the app using the “en” locale instead of the “fr” one when the set language is “fr_FR”?

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem:

In Info.plist, the development language was set to France, when changed to US the problem disappeared.